# Way to aggragate multiple json array element in column in postgres. All the colmns json array to be appended to create new array

Tags: json, postgresql

Below is sample data

### Sample table

`id |  data_value
    1  |  [{"a":"f1"},{"b":"b1"},{"c":"c1"}]
    2  |  [{"a":"f2"},{"b":"b2"},{"c":"c2"}]
    3  |  [{"a":"f3"},{"b":"b2"},{"c":"c3"}]
    4  |  [{"a":"f4"},{"b":"b3"},{"c":"v4"}]
    5  |  [{"a":"f5"},{"b":"b4"},{"c":"c4"}]`

Result

```
`[{"a":"f1"},{"b":"b1"},{"c":"c1"},{"a":"f2"},{"b":"b2"},{"c":"c2"},"a":"f3"},{"b":"b2"},{"c":"c3"}{"a":"f4"},{"b":"b3"},{"c":"v4"},    {"a":"f5"},{"b":"b4"},{"c":"c4"}]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=# select ('['||translate(json_agg(dv)::text,'[]','')||']')::jsonb from d1;
                                                                                                jsonb

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------
 [{"a": "f1"}, {"b": "b1"}, {"c": "c1"}, {"a": "f2"}, {"b": "b2"}, {"c": "c2"}, {"a": "f3"}, {"b": "b2"}, {"c": "c3"}, {"a": "f4"}, {"b": "b3"}, {"c": "v4"}, {"a": "f5"}, {"b": "b4"},
{"c": "c4"}]
(1 row)
```

or neater SQL, but requires some build:

```
create or replace function json_agg_arr(jsonb,jsonb) returns jsonb as $$
  select case when coalesce($1::text, '') <> '' then $1 || $2 else $2 end;
$$ language sql called on null input;

create aggregate json_agg_arr (jsonb) (sfunc=json_agg_arr,stype=jsonb);
```

and then just aggregate rows:

```
t=# select json_agg_arr(dv::jsonb) from d1;
                                                                                            json_agg_arr

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------
 [{"a": "f1"}, {"b": "b1"}, {"c": "c1"}, {"a": "f2"}, {"b": "b2"}, {"c": "c2"}, {"a": "f3"}, {"b": "b2"}, {"c": "c3"}, {"a": "f4"}, {"b": "b3"}, {"c": "v4"}, {"a": "f5"}, {"b": "b4"},
{"c": "c4"}]
(1 row)
```